# Query for results based on date-time datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table : **Orders**

```
Column     Datatype
------     --------
orderid     int 
orderdate   date
customerid  int
```

We need a query which return orders placed on June 2016.

I tried

```
  Select orderid 
  from  Orders
  where orderdate between 2016-06-01 and 2016-06-30
```

It gives error because between works with `int` only.How to do now to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing `'` when specifying the date range. Also, you need to cast `orderdate` as `DATE`. The reason is because if you have data like '2016-06-30 12:34:56', `BETWEEN '2016-06-01' and '2016-06-30'` will not return the record.

```
Select orderid 
from  Orders
where CONVERT(DATE, orderdate) between '2016-06-01' and '2016-06-30'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `YEAR()` to extract the year from a given date and `MONTH()` for the month.

```
SELECT orderid FROM Orders 
WHERE YEAR(orderdate) = 2016 and MONTH(orderdate) = 6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Select orderid from  Orders where DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, 
orderdate)) between DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, 2016-06-01)) and 
DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, 2016-06-30))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should also work:

```
select orderid
from orders
where orderdate >= '2016-06-01'
and orderdate < '2016-07-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

[BETWEEN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) does not work with `int` only, you can use it for `date` columns, too. Try the following:

```
SELECT 
    [orderid]
FROM [Orders]
WHERE [orderdate] BETWEEN '2016-06-01' AND '2016-06-30'
```

Or you can make use of the `YEAR` and `MONTH` functions:

```
SELECT 
    [orderid]
FROM [Orders]
WHERE YEAR([orderdate]) = 2016
      AND MONTH([orderdate]) = 6
```

This approach can, however, result in performance problems, as there are no indexes to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Please use single quotes around the dates

```
 Select orderid 
  from  Orders
  where orderdate between '2016-06-01' and '2016-06-30'
```